# Create a port mapping with Open.NAT problem

Tags: c#, port, portforwarding

I am trying to use a library [Open.NAT](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT) to create port map, but receive error

> Open.Nat.MappingException: 'Failed to create portmap (protocol=Tcp, private port=12630)'

Here is my code. Where is a problem?

```
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            NatDiscoverer discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
            NatDevice device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync();

            int port = GetAvailablePort(1000);

            Mapping mapping = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, port, port, "Test mapping");

            await device.CreatePortMapAsync(mapping);    

            Console.WriteLine("The external IP Address is: {0} ", await device.GetExternalIPAsync());

            Console.ReadLine();

            await device.DeletePortMapAsync(mapping);
        }
```

This function for find free port

```
        public static int GetAvailablePort(int startingPort)
        {
            List<int> portArray = new List<int>();

            IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            
            TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in connections
                               where n.LocalEndPoint.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.LocalEndPoint.Port);

            
            IPEndPoint[] endPoints = properties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in endPoints
                               where n.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.Port);

            
            endPoints = properties.GetActiveUdpListeners();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in endPoints
                               where n.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.Port);

            portArray.Sort();

            for (int i = startingPort; i < ushort.MaxValue; i++)
            { 
                if (!portArray.Contains(i))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Implicit in your question is a claim that your computer is in fact connected to a NAT router, and that the NAT router does in fact support UPnP, and that the router's UPnP support is in fact enabled. Frankly, without a [mcve] it's practically impossible to provide a useful answer to a question like this, but you need to at least make sure that the network configuration is correct as well (which isn't a programming question, but rather a network admin question).

Comment: If assuming that something wrong in my network configuration but how UTorrent work on my computer and download files? )

Comment: You'd have to ask the UTorrent developers, or inspect the code yourself. That said, there are ways to navigate a NAT router other than UPnP. See e.g. "hole punching".

Answer (score 0):

This exception is a sign of **port is being used by another process**

you need to check whether the 12630 port is already being used by another process, and if it is you need to kill it or change the port number.

Also I suggest you to check innerException and/or ErrorCode for details

possible errorCodes:

```
InvalidArguments = 402
ActionFailed = 501
Unathorized = 606
SpecifiedArrayIndexInvalid = 713        
NoSuchEntryInArray = 714
WildCardNotPermittedInSourceIp = 715
WildCardNotPermittedInExternalPort = 716
ConflictInMappingEntry = 718
SamePortValuesRequired = 724
OnlyPermanentLeasesSupported = 725
RemoteHostOnlySupportsWildcard = 726
ExternalPortOnlySupportsWildcard = 727
NoPortMapsAvailable = 728
ConflictWithOtherMechanisms = 729
WildCardNotPermittedInIntPort = 732
```

Comment: InnerException is null and Error Code equals 0. As you see in code I'm have a code to find Free TCP Port

Comment: What find are you using? There is no looping.  What are your Start and Stop port numbers?

Comment: I have edited function for find Free available post, please check function GetAvailablePort in my first post, but problem still exists